# I am trying to print all the database users in a Unordered list in PHP. But it is not working

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $sql  = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM loginsystem";

        if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
            if ($total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
                while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) : ?>
                    <li>
                    <?php $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name']; ?>
                    </li>
    <?php 
                endwhile;
                mysqli_free_result($result);
            }
        }
    ?>
    </ul>
```

The above code is not working. Please help to solve this issue. Please help me

Comment: *How* is not not working? What results to do you get? What are you expecting to get? What errors do you get, if any?

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly. Use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get a detailed error message from the database.

Comment: I'd recommend against mixing standard and alternative control structure syntax.  (if { } and while: endwhile), stick with one or the other so your code is readable.

Answer (score 4):

You are not actually outputing anything in your while loop, you need only add an `echo` to this line

```
<?php echo $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name']; ?>
```